# proble with pgfplotstable and column type=>{\raggedright}p{}

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, columns

I have a couple of cvs-files which I want to include with pgfplotstable. Most of the fields are text. The individual columns should be of the type `>{\raggedright}p{}` for automatic line break and left-aligned text.

The following MWE explains my problem.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=semicolon,string type,
    columns/col1/.style={column type=>{\raggedright}p{.2\textwidth}},
    columns/col2/.style={column type=>{\raggedright}p{.2\textwidth}},
    % columns/col2/.style={column type=p{.2\textwidth}}
    ]
    {
        col1;col2
        long text with multiple lines;long text with multiple lines
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this leads to the following error:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign 
                {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global \@...
l.20    }

I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

However, if I comment the first line with columns/col2/ out and use the second (commented) line, everything compiles, I just don't get the left alignment for the last column. If there are more columns it's always the last column which causes problems. Does anybody know, how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `\arraybackslash` from `array` package after `\raggedright`.

For the reason why, the answer to this post: [What is \arraybackslash doing on my table column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387737/what-is-arraybackslash-doing-on-my-table-column).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=semicolon,string type,
        columns/col1/.style={column type={>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.2\textwidth}}},
        columns/col2/.style={column type={>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.2\textwidth}}},
        ]
        {
            col1;col2
            long text with multiple lines;long text with multiple lines
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]