# Changing the column order breaks tabularx

Tags: tables, errors, tabularx, booktabs

Why does the following table breaks with TeX saying that

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.9 \end{tabularx}

?
```

If I change the column specification from `c>{\raggedright}X` to `>{\raggedright}Xc` (that is, change the order) the document compiles correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{2cm}{c>{\raggedright}X}
  a & b \\
  % \midrule Yet another error
  c & d \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, if I use one of `booktabs`'s rules in the middle of the table (not before the first row, not after the second, but in the middle, specifically), the error changes. I assume that it's a consequence of the first, so perhaps solving the first this one will disappear too.

Comment: use `\raggedright\arraybackslash` (see the tabularx doc)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The docs, of course... Thank you very much. Do you want to post an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: Related: [What is` \arraybackslash` doing on my table column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387737/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\raggedright\arraybackslash` where `\arraybackslash` restores `\\` to its "end of table row" meaning,