# Various errors when adding new row or horizontal line to table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, cline, hline

I'm trying to replicate the table from Annex A of the ISO/IEC 27001 standard:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{longtable}{| l | >{\raggedright}p{0.2\textwidth} | >{\raggedright}p{0.7\textwidth} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|>{\raggedright}p{\textwidth}|}{\textbf{Text text text}} \\           
    \hline
    Lorem & ipsum & text \\
\end{longtable}
```

However, adding almost anything between the 'Lorem ipsum' row and the `\end{longtable}` causes compilation to fail, but in different ways.

Adding another row of cells containing text causes the following:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.195                       Lorem2 &
                        ipsum2 & text2 \\
```

Adding `\hline` causes the following:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.195                       \hline
```

And adding `\cline{1-3}` causes the following:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\@cline #1-#2\@nil ->\omit 
                           \@multicnt #1\advance \@multispan \m@ne \ifnum \@...
l.195                       \cline{1-3}
```

This happens whether I use the `longtable` or `tabular` environment.

The only thing that I can add that won't break it is a single text cell, e.g.:

```
    Lorem & ipsum & text \\
    adsfdsfdsf
\end{longtable}
```

I am at a complete loss as to what is wrong here. Every other question I can find with the same error is using different packages or nesting things in a way I am not.

The fact that compilation fails no matter what I add makes me think the actual error messages are red herrings, but I have no idea how to debug whatever the underlying issue may be without that information.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try to change `>{\raggedright}` to `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` in the definition of the last column.

Comment: Ah! That's done it, thanks a lot. If you or anyone else fancies explaining how that fixed it in a full answer I'll accept it and close the question.

Comment: I think, this question has already been answered, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387737/what-is-arraybackslash-doing-on-my-table-column).