# Is this the correct way to produce a table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

After reading through tutorials, documentations and posts, I tried to design a table on my own.
The final result looks exactly as it should be :-)

However, I am not sure if I did it the right way. In my opinion, the code looks quite confusing.

So my question, is there a better/more elegant way to design this table?

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llXcccccc}
  \toprule
   {} & {} & {} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Implic. QA} & {\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=r, y=5pt]{90}{Dtaa Lnq.}}}  \\
    \cmidrule(lllll){4-8}
     Source & NBame & Description & \rotatebox{90}{Accin.} & \rotatebox{90}{Lomp.} & \rotatebox{90}{Ronsi.} & \rotatebox{90}{Volti.} & \rotatebox{90}{Curre.} &  \\ \addlinespace
   
    \midrule
    
     \multirow{4}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Hugo \\ et al.}} & \multirow{4}{*}{Brasilia} & The organization, The organization The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization. & \multirow{4}{*}{-}  & \multirow{4}{*}{-} & \multirow{4}{*}{x} & \multirow{4}{*}{-} & \multirow{4}{*}{-} & \multirow{4}{*}{-} \\ \addlinespace
     
     \multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Manuel \\et al.}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Nort Carolina} & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & \multirow{3}{*}{-}  & \multirow{3}{*}{x} & \multirow{3}{*}{x} & \multirow{3}{*}{-} & \multirow{3}{*}{-} & \multirow{3}{*}{-} \\ \addlinespace
    
     \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Otto \\ et al.}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Manchester} & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & \multirow{2}{*}{-}  & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} \\ \addlinespace%[20pt]
     
     \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Marx \\\& Weak}} & \multirow{2}{*}{France} & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & \multirow{2}{*}{x}  & \multirow{2}{*}{x} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{x} & \multirow{2}{*}{x} \\ \addlinespace
     
     \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Oliver \\\& Wolfor}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Germany} & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & \multirow{2}{*}{-}  & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{x} & \multirow{2}{*}{-} & \multirow{2}{*}{x} \\ \addlinespace
    
     \multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Humbold \\et al.}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Hunbary} & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & \multirow{3}{*}{-}  & \multirow{3}{*}{-} & \multirow{3}{*}{-} & \multirow{3}{*}{x} & \multirow{3}{*}{-} & \multirow{3}{*}{-} \\ 
    
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please ignore the content of the table.

Thank you very much and best regards,
Harald

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This is a good first question.  For future questions, it would help us if you could include everything we would need to compile.  In this case, that would be `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{multirow,rotating,tabularx,booktabs}` like in the answers.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. I thought I had provided all these infos in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine, but there are way too many unnecessary `\multirow`s. You actually don't need any in the table body. The problem might be that the `X` column vertically aligns to the top and not to the middle by default. The documentation for `tabularx` gives an idea on how to change that.

My suggestion of how to improve the code a bit:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Table}

 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{1.3cm}lXcccccc}
  \toprule
   {} & {} & {} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Implic. QA} & {\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=r, y=5pt]{90}{Dtaa Lnq.}}}  \\
    \cmidrule(lllll){4-8}
     Source & NBame & Description & \rotatebox{90}{Accin.} & \rotatebox{90}{Lomp.} & \rotatebox{90}{Ronsi.} & \rotatebox{90}{Volti.} & \rotatebox{90}{Curre.} &  \\ \addlinespace
    \midrule
    Hugo et al. & Brasilia & The organization, The organization The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization. & -  & - & x & - & - & - \\ \addlinespace
    Manuel et al. & Nort Carolina & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & -  & x & x & - & - & - \\ \addlinespace
    Otto\break et al. & Manchester & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ \addlinespace%[20pt]
    Marx\break \& Weak & France & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & x  & x & - & - & x & x \\ \addlinespace
    Oliver\break \& Wolfor & Germany & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & -  & - & - & x & - & x \\ \addlinespace
    Humbold et al. & Hunbary & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image & - & - & - & x & - & - \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! One question regarding \renewcommand: does this affect all further tables in the document? I ask because it is not embedded in the table environment of this actual table.

Comment: `\renewcommand` makes all `X` columns vertically centered. If it's the only one table where centering required, then it's better to redefine `\tabularxcolumn` locally.

Comment: locally mean within the table environment? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The folllwing simplified version of the table code should result in a similar output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table}
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{1.25cm}lXcccccc}
  \toprule
   {} & {} & {} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Implic. QA} & {\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=r, y=5pt]{90}{Dtaa Lnq.}}}  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-8}
     Source & NBame & Description & \rotatebox{90}{Accin.} & \rotatebox{90}{Lomp.} & \rotatebox{90}{Ronsi.} & \rotatebox{90}{Volti.} & \rotatebox{90}{Curre.} &  \\ \addlinespace
   
    \midrule
    
     Hugo et al. 
       & Brasilia 
         & The organization, The organization The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization, The organization. 
           & -  & - & x & - & - & - \\ \addlinespace
     
     Manuel et al. 
       & Nort Carolina 
         & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image 
           & - & x & x & - & - & - \\ \addlinespace
    
     Otto et al. 
       & Manchester 
         & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image 
           & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ \addlinespace%[20pt]
     
     Marx \& Weak 
       & France 
         & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image 
           & x  & x & - & - & x & x \\ \addlinespace
     
     Oliver \& Wolfor 
       & Germany 
         & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image 
           & - & - & - & x & - & x \\ \addlinespace
    
     Humbold et al. 
       & Hunbary 
         & Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image Image 
           & - & - & - & x & - & - \\ 
    
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Heh. Almost the same changes as mine.

Comment: thank you! what is \arraybackslash actually doing?

Comment: **add1**  how can I make the space between all columns equal?

**add2**: how can I make the space between, e.g. 'Oliver' and '& Wolfor' smaller?

Comment: @HaraldFoidl: The horizontal spaces between columns should already be equal. Could you explicitly point out, which distances appear to be uneven. Maybe I'm overlooking something? Does "the space between, e.g. 'Oliver' and '& Wolfor' "  refer to the vertical distance between the two lines? Chenging the spacing there would result in the two lines no longer being in line with the contents of the third column, yo I wouldn't recommend doing that. Regarding the use of `\arraybackslash`: [Alan Munn explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387741/134144) it better than I could in their answer.